# How can I determine the amount of disk space used by my Lightroom photo collection?

Tags: lightroom

I'm trying to determine the disk space used by a (smart) collection.

I'm aware that the collection itself technically doesn't need any disk space, so what I want to know is basically the combined file size of every picture in that collection.

Answer (score 2):

You can use John Beardsworth's [FolderSize Plugin](http://lightroomsolutions.com/plug-ins/foldersize/). Unticking 'Folders View' will give you the size of all selected files as well as their sum.

[image]

Altenatively Jeffrey Friedl's [DataExplorer Plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/data-explorer#criteria) should be able to give you this information as well (see 'File Size (bytes)' on that site), but I haven't used it.